# Mixed bayes problem

Tags: probability

How would I do the following problem. I do have an answer but not sure it is correct.

Let $S$ be a discrete random variable that takes 1 and -1 with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$ redpectively. Let $X$ be a continuous random variable whose conditional distribution given $S$ is as follows:

$f_{X|S}(x|1)=\alpha e^{-\alpha x}$ for $x\ge 0$ and $\alpha>0$

$f_{X|S}(x|-1)=\beta e^{\beta x}$ for $x\le 0$ and $\beta>0$

a) For $x>0$ find $f_X(x)$

b) For $x<0$ find $f_X(x)$

For a) I got $f_X(x)=p\alpha e^{-\alpha x}$

For b) I got $f_X(x)=(1-p)\beta e^{\beta x}$

Are these correct?

Comment: It's only a minor point, but it would be better to refer to $f_X(x)$ as the *probability density function* of $X$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you think the answers are correct?

Comment: At a glance the total probability given by your (a) + (b) gives one, so that's a good sign.  I did not try to rederive your conclusions though.